# BIRT page layout and control through javascript

Tags: birt

I have the following questions regarding paged layout and if someone can help me, I will really appreciate it

1) Is it possible to show everything as a single page and bring a scroll bar if the number of charts don't fit into first page.

2) Similarly, If I want a specific object .i.e a table to stay within a fixed frame on page1 or page2 and bring a scroll-bar within its own frame if there is too many records. The scrollbar should be only within table's frame and not the whole page

3) I am controlling the size of charts and grid through javascript (inside text items/elements). If I click on a button, it makes the size of grid and objects to 0px and all the charts below it comes up as I made the heights of the top objects to 0px through javascript.

However, the objects from page 2 do not come to page1. Can someone please suggest how can I bring the objects from page 2/3/4 to page1 if I have made the heights of all objects to opx and hidden them through the javascript button

4) Is it possible to go to a specific page through a button/javascript function?

Thanks and Regards

Arif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) It is possible to increase the height of the Master page, so that all chart elements fit in one single page

2) Javascript is required for this. A simple approach would be to set a height value to the table through Eclipse designer, and then apply this styling through javascript:

```
display:block
overflow:scroll
```

For more complex requirements (such fixed headers/footers), a javascript plugin [such this one](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html) might help.

3)This is related to 1). A birt report is streamed page by page, elements from another page can't be reached by javascript code.

4) Pagination can be controlled through an url parameter __page, see this [viewer documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/viewer-usage.php). For example you could define image elements with a drillthrough action to go to these pages. We can also make use of bookmarks for this: it is probably much more appropriate because we don't have to forecast precisely the number of pages.